# Return from a statement after callback is complete

Tags: java, android, callback

Basically I'm looking for a smart way to have the function return after the callback within dbInteractionComplete has finished running.

Currently the function returns before the callback has completed, obviously. Maybe there is a smart way of getting the return to wait until the callback has finished?

```
private List<Post> toggle() {

    final List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>();
    final QuestionnaireWrapper mCurrentQuestionnaireWrapper = DatabaseHelper.getCurrentQuestionnaire(teamId);
    if (mCurrentQuestionnaireWrapper != null) {
        if (mCurrentQuestionnaireWrapper.isCompleted()) {
            final QuestionnaireFeedbackDialog mQuestionnaireFeedbackDialog = QuestionnaireFeedbackDialog.newInstance(mCurrentQuestionnaireWrapper.getQuestionnaire().getFeedback());
            mQuestionnaireFeedbackDialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "questionnaire_feedback");
            final String uniqueId = teamId + "," + mCurrentQuestionnaireWrapper.getRemoteId();
            DatabaseHelper.deleteQuestionnaire(teamId, uniqueId, new DBCallbackInterface() {
                @Override
                public void dbInteractionComplete() {
                    final QuestionnaireWrapper mNextCurrentQuestionnaire = DatabaseHelper.getCurrentQuestionnaire(teamId);
                    if (mNextCurrentQuestionnaire != null) {
                        mCurrentQuestionnaire = mNextCurrentQuestionnaire.getQuestionnaire();
                        final Post post = new Post();
                        post.setType(Questionnaire.QUESTIONNAIRE_FEED_TYPE);
                        postList.add(post);
                    }
                }
            });
            return postList;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Return from a statement after callback is complete Java android

Generally callback interfaces are used for async execution, so you should not wait until the callback has finished. In android blocking UI thread may cause app to crash too.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface :
`public interface SomeInterface { void callback (List<Post>) ;}`

Create a class which implements `DBCallbackInterface`:

```
    public static class SomeNewClass implements DBCallbackInterface {

    private List<Post> list;

    private SomeInterface iAmAwsome;
    private int teamId;
    public SomeNewClass(List<Post> list, SomeInterface iAmAwsome, int teamId) {

    this.list = list;

    this.iAmAwsome = iAmAwsome;

    this.teamId = teamId;
    }

    @Override
     public void dbInteractionComplete() {
final QuestionnaireWrapper mNextCurrentQuestionnaire = DatabaseHelper.getCurrentQuestionnaire(teamId);
  if (mNextCurrentQuestionnaire != null) {
                                mCurrentQuestionnaire = mNextCurrentQuestionnaire.getQuestionnaire();
                                final Post post = new Post();
                                post.setType(Questionnaire.QUESTIONNAIRE_FEED_TYPE);              list.add(post);

    if (iAmAwsome! = null) 
iAmAwsome.callback(list) ;
    }
    }
```

Usage: inside your toggle method :

```
DatabaseHelper.deleteQuestionnaire(teamId, uniqueId,  new SomeNewClass(postList, new SomeInterface() {
@Override
                public void callback(List<Post>yourdata){code here } }, teamId)
```

Comment: unfortunately this has left me in the same position with a callback instead of a return on the toggle function. Thanks though!

Comment: @HannahLouisaCarney , if corunites exist in Java I would suggest them. But they don't.

Comment: @HannahLouisaCarney, they only solution is to call callback like in my example.